# Numpy dot product of a 4D array with its transpose fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, array-broadcasting

For a 4D array A with dimensions of (60,64,2,2), need to calculate the dot product with its transpose A_t.

A_t is of dimension(2,2,64,60). Below is what I do.

```
A_t = np.transpose(A)
A_At = A_t.dot(A)
```

The dot product throws an error

```
ValueError: shapes (2,2,64,60) and (60,64,2,2) not aligned: 60 (dim 3) != 2 (dim 2)
```

Am I taking the transpose incorrectly? I have also tried converting the individual arrays to numpy matrices(even though not recommended as per several posts) and then computing the dot product but I get a different error.

Have also researched numpy topics such as broadcasting but I could not find any useful example for 4D arrays.

Any inputs would be grateful. Thanks!

Note: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: What's the shape of expected output? Can you add a working loopy solution?

Comment: I'm expecting the output to be a 2x2

Comment: Think of `dot` as sum of products.  How you going to pair up the axes when multiplying, and which products will you sum.

Comment: Add a plain python tag to your question.

Comment: And keep in mind that dot reduces one axis per call.

Comment: From the [docstring of `numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html): "If `a` is an N-D array and `b` is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of `a` and the second-to-last axis of `b`:   `dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])`"

Comment: What makes you think that what you want is a 2x2 array at the end?

Comment: `the individual arrays to numpy matrices` - what do you mean by this?  Be precise.  I might guess that you have 60*64 arrays, each of size (2,2).  Or maybe 4 arrays of size (60,64).  Dot or matrix product is well defined for 2 2d arrays, but there are all kinds of ways of extending the concept to 4d.

Comment: @Divakar Your answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977238/intuition-and-idea-behind-reshaping-4d-array-to-2d-array-in-numpy) is great! Turns out it is not straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*On your knowledge-driven wish of having a 2x2 array at the end*, what about using [xarray.dot](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.dot.html) for that kind of task. With your `A` in hand

```
>>> A.shape
(60, 64, 2, 2)
```

you would do

```
>>> xA   = xr.DataArray(A, dims=['d1','d2','d3','d4'])
>>> xA_t = xA.T
>>> xr.dot(xA_t, xA, dims=['d1','d2']).shape
(2, 2)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `xarray.dot`, but it looks like it's doing something similar to `np.tensordot`.

Comment: With `C = numpy.tensordot(A, A, axes=([0,1],[0,1]))` you would have to do `np.array([C[0,0,0,0], C[1,0,1,0], C[0,1,0,1], C[1,1,1,1]]).reshape((2,2))` to get the same result as `xr.dot`.